# Can something be inserted between "你能借我橡皮" and "用一下吗?"?

Tags: grammar, preposition, conjunction

> 你能借我橡皮用一下吗?
>
> 你(you)能(able)借(lend)我(me)橡皮(an eraser)用(which is to be used)一下(for a moment)吗(ok)?

I have 2 translations against the original sentence.

- Can you lend me an eraser for a moment? (free translation which was got from deepL)
- Can you lend me an eraser **which is to be/for** used for a moment (my translation which is an unnatural translation but I think that this sentence is more closer to the original sentence).

For me, I want something like corresponding "for" in English, between  "你能借我橡皮" and "用一下吗?"

I want to know your thoughts about this.

Answer (score 1):

You may think “你能借我橡皮用一下吗” is a little ambiguous. However, this is a really native oral expression. I guess this sentence is just an abbreviation of "你能借我橡皮吗，我想用一下"(Could you lend me an eraser? I would like to use it for a moment).

You don't need to insert anything between them.

Answer (score 1):

> 你能借我橡皮用一下吗?

I think the fixes below are acceptable:

- 你能借橡皮**給我**用一下吗?
- 你能把橡皮**借我**用一下吗?